# SCNScene load with textures from pod

Tags: cocoapods, textures, bundle, scenekit, scnscene

I am trying to create pod which contains SCNScene with textures and got an error:

```
SceneKit Error: Failed loading : C3DImage
src:file:///Users/.../Example.app/Templates.scnassets/grid.png
```

Texture and scene are in the same folder.

I've tried to load with SCNSceneSource

```
let sceneData = try Data(contentsOf: sceneUrl)
let options = [.overrideAssetURLs: true,
               .assetDirectoryURLs: MYPod.bundle().bundleURL
               ] as [SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption : Any]
let source = SCNSceneSource(data: sceneData, options:options)
scene = (source?.scene(options: options))!
```

but got same result (path not changing)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Very raw. After loading, if the content of the material is string (name of the texture), building correct path and loading UIImage manually

Comment: @Андрей Первушин can you explain more details

Comment: You should go trough all of the materials with the code and if
(sorry for pseudo code)

If material.contents.type == String.type {
material.contents = UIImage(named: <path tofolder>/material.contents)
}

Comment: @Андрей Первушин Thanks mate. Finally its works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go trough all of the materials with the code and (sorry for pseudo code)

```
If material.contents.type == String.type { 
material.contents = UIImage(named: <path tofolder>/material.contents) 
}
```

Comment: Do we need to iterate through all the child nodes and apply contents? What if i have multiple child nodes inside a child node? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: On trying out this code, i am getting this error "Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'type'"

Comment: this is pseudo code, you'll have interpret logic for current swift version